# How to have network sharing between a lan to wan Firewall Setup?

Tags: networking, router, firewall, lan

I have a Dlink Router wherein one its LAN ports are connected to a Gajshield Firewalls wan port.

The firewall has a Static Wan IP assigned to it from the Dlink LAN network. There is a inbound policy on the Firewall that allows to accept any incoming connections from the Dlinks network only. I have put a static route from the Dlink's network to the Gajshields LAN network.

The thing is that I can ping/http/web to the Gajshield's internal network across its wan interface from the Dlink's LAN but I cant figure out how to conduct sharing between the two networks.

Any suggestions on how to go about it?

Comment: Can anybody help...